# C, Passing a pointer of a file to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)

{
    int good_file = 0;        //flag                    
    FILE* files[argc - 1];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++){

    if ((files[i]=fopen(argv[i+1], "r"))==NULL)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else                  //if file is good
    {
        good_file++;  //increment then pass the ptr
        test(files[i]);  //of file to test function
    }                         
}

    if(!good_file){              //if flag good_file is 0 error
        printf("ERROR!");
    }
exit(0);                           //then exit program

}

int test (int *file)                //takes in ptr to file[i] as param

{
    char c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
            putc(c, stdout);
        fclose(file);
    return main             //return main and continue loop

}
```

I know my code is a mess but I am trying to take in an X amount of files and then have the program test to make sure that the file isn't empty or doesn't exist and then print out the contents of it in a different function. I am trying to find a way to successfully pass a pointer to a file as a parameter so it's contents can then be printed to stdout in a different function. Then when done, have that function return control back to the main function for the loop to continue its process.

Comment: First: **indent your code correctly!**. What are you supposed to do if a file fails to open? If your spec is all or nothing, you are on the right track: open all files and if successful, make a seconf loop to copy all file contents to `stdout`.  If a file fails to open, `fprintf` the error message to `stderr` instead of `stdout` so it is visible even if you redirect output to a file.  In the copy loop, use `int c;` instead of `char c;` so you can distinguish `EOF` from all valid `char` values.  Use `FILE *` instead of `int *` in `test()`.

Comment: If you know that your program is a mess, the best thing would be cleaning it up first.

Comment: Think what would happen when I pass no arguments. You have to check `argc`

Comment: Ahh yes if there is no arguments I will need to have a test before anything. Thanks for pointing that out. I have since fixed that and changed int *file to FILE* file.

Comment: chqrlie, thanks for the insight... it's cleared up a lot and I will make adjustments!

Answer (score 1):

Your `test` function is bogous (using `int` instead of `FILE` in the parameter and using `char` instead of `int` for `fgetc`.

Try this:

```
void test (FILE *file)                //takes in ptr to file[i] as param
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
       putc(c, stdout);

    fclose(file);
}
```

There may be more issues though.

Comment: It is also inconsistent to `fclose()` the `FILE *` in `test()` instead of `main()`

Comment: The naked `return;` statement at the end of this function is redundant, and this function should be defined as `void`.

Comment: How could I return control back to the main function in case there is a second file that needs to be read and outputted?

Comment: @collinskewl2 not quite sure what you mean by "return control back to the main function". You call `test`from the main function, and as soon as `test` has finished you return to the calling function. That's how function calls work.